# How to correctly sync time of an Hyper-V host which is member of a domain?

Tags: hyper-v, domain-controller, ntp, time-synchronization

There are many posts concerning issues when dealing with time synchronisation over a domain which holds virtualised PDC Emulators ([see this article](https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/hyper-v-time-synchronization/)).

As a result our PDC Emulator time (and domain time), although configured to sync from an authoritative NTP server, was wrong because of the Hyper-V Integration services/Time synchronisation. As soon as this was disabled, the PDC emulator (and domain) time began synchronising correctly, but the Hyper-V host time kept being wrong.

I suspect the Hyper-V host (2019) is not synchronising time from the domain.

How can I ensure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an elevated command prompt on the Hyper-V host run the following:

```
net stop w32time
w32tm /unregister
w32tm /register
net start w32time
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:DOMHIER /update
net stop w32time
net start w32time
```

Comment: @joeqwerty, it would be great if you could expand the answer a little to explain what those commands do.  I assume they are telling Windows to ignore NTP and use the domain's time sync services instead, but it would be nice if this could be made explicit in the answer.